# Change position of span

Tags: html, angular-material2, angular-material-6

How can I change the position of the span-tag to have it in the center next to the icon?

[image]

That's the following code currently:

```
mat-card-content {
    padding: 50px;
}

.box-position {
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <div class="box-position">
            <mat-icon>warning</mat-icon>
            <span>Page not found!</span>
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` on the span, and maybe also on the icon. This should come close to what you need?

Comment: @elveti Thanks for your comment. It helped me :)

Comment: You can simply use the **vertical-align** property to accomplish this